# Can't use \PassOptionsToClass in beamer by cls document

Tags: beamer

The `MWE`:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{format}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  My name is chichi.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

my `.cls` file:

```
% format.cls
\PassOptionsToClass{20pt,aspectratio = 1610}{ beamer }

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{format}[23/06/2023]

\LoadClass{beamer}
```

However, if I use `\PassOptionsToClass` directly in `.tex` file, it will be useful, like this:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{20pt,aspectratio = 1610}{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  My name is chichi.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Because I want to design a user interface that changes the beamer size and font size in beamer template, I use `\PassOptionsToClass` in the `.cls` file.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `.cls` to:

```
% format.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{format}
\PassOptionsToClass{20pt,aspectratio = 1610}{beamer}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{beamer}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and I found that the \PassOptionsToClass command does not use spaces for the Class, which I added to the code for aesthetics.

Comment: @user1159339 You should *always* [be careful with extra spaces and even end of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/277964) (unless you are in `expl3` context).